# Handling mysql using PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

So, I have a mysql database patients where is a client table. I need to show information about clients in GUI window in table. Also I need a filter by main fields to get more detailed information (separately surname, name, series of documents, a series of policy, etc.) with the possibility to search simultaneously in multiple fields. I started with code below.
The question number 1 is: What is easy to use in this task - QSqlTableModel or just QTableWidget?
The question number 2 is: How to filter by main fields? What that mean? 
I would be very glad to any thoughts on the subject.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtSql import *
import sys

def main_():
    app     = QApplication(sys.argv)
    table   = QTableWidget()
    db      = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")


    db.setHostName("127.0.0.1")
    db.setDatabaseName("patients")
    db.setUserName("root")
    db.setPassword("")
    table_name = "client"

    if (db.open()==False):
      QMessageBox.critical(None, "Database Error",
                db.lastError().text())

    query = QSqlQuery ("select * from "+ table_name + " limit 10")

    table.setColumnCount(query.record().count())
    table.setRowCount(query.size())

    index=0
    while (query.next()):
        table.setItem(index,0,QTableWidgetItem(query.value(0).toString()))
        table.setItem(index,1,QTableWidgetItem(query.value(1).toString()))
        index += 1
    table.show()
    return app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would like to read more about Model-View concept.

After opening your database connection, you create a model of the data, then attach it to the view... no iterating needed:

```
model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
# selecting a table
model.setTable("clients")
# applying a filter
model.setFilter("id > 0")
# i.e.: executing the query
model.select()

# the widget to show the data
tableView = QTableView()
# attach the model to widget
tableView.setModel(model)


tableView.show()
```

Also: if you cannot open the database - exit the program, not only present a message box.

I hope that helps a bit.